# How to get Nodes in embedded Neo4j with multiple Labels?

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a neo4j database and I use embedded mode. There are millions of nodes with multiple labels with each node. I can get all the nodes with single label like

```
    GlobalGraphOperations gb = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb);
    ResourceIterable iterable = gb.getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label("LABEL1"));
```

This is fine. Now I want to do the same thing but with multiple labels. I want all the nodes which have "LABEL1" and "LABEL2" and "LABEL3" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Internally Neo4j maintains a labelscanstore that gives you quickly an iterator for all nodes with a given label - but there's no such scan store for combination of labels.

If you want to find all nodes sharing multiple labels the strategy is to iterate over all nodes for the "cheapest" label - aka the one with the least number of nodes - and filter that for the other labels.

The code snippet below uses a try-with-resources and a JDK 8 lambda (n case of < JDK8 just create a class implementing `Predicate`. I'm assuming `LABEL1` is the label with the fewest nodes:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.helpers.Predicate;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.FilteringIterator;

...

try (ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = 
    graphDatabaseService.findNodes(DynamicLabel.label("LABEL1"))) {

    Iterator<Node> nodeWithAllLabels = new FilteringIterator<>(nodes,
            node -> node.hasLabel(DynamicLabel.label("LABEL2")) && 
                    node.hasLabel(DynamicLabel.label("LABEL3"))
    );

    // do stuff with nodeWithAllLabels
}
```

Comment: Let me check that out with Predicate. Sounds like some sort of callbacks.

Comment: How do I implement my own predicate? I have a feeling that the predicate should have to iterate through the rest of the nodes, every time. Is there any traversal that I can do, starting from some known reference node? The graph is such that the Labels are the edges in the undirected, weighted graph.

Comment: Update: I used the Filter with Predicate, and found it took around 300 ms to iterate over more than 5 millions nodes. Do you have any suggestion on how to take that down to less than 10 ms? Is caching necessary to get that  or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Neo4j's cache should already help. Can you try to run that multiple times to see if it gets faster?

Comment: Stefan, you seems like an employee of neo4j! If it is true, can you point me to where should I go to find if I am hitting the database or cache(index)? And things like that?

Comment: how about finding nodes with multiple properties?

Answer (score 2):

You could [execute a Cypher query](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html). Here is a code snippet:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "required", Arrays.asList( "LABEL1", "LABEL2", "LABEL3" ) );
String query = "MATCH (n) WHERE ALL(x IN {required} WHERE x IN LABELS(n)) RETURN n";
Result result = db.execute( query, params );
```

[UPDATE]

However, the above query would iterate through all the nodes, which is not performant.

Thanks to @StefanArmbruster's suggestion, we can make the above query more efficient by specifying the least likely label in the `MATCH` clause (to take advantage of the internally-generated node label index):

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "otherLabels", Arrays.asList( "LABEL2", "LABEL3" ) );
String query = "MATCH (n:LABEL1) WHERE ALL(x IN {otherLabels} WHERE x IN LABELS(n)) RETURN n";
Result result = db.execute( query, params );
```

Comment: That looks ugly. I would rather play with the API. I am not doing a single query, everything should be embedded.

Comment: the above cypher statement will in fact iterate over all nodes and then apply the filter. You can be more efficient by doing the match on the "cheapest" label and apply the filter on this smaller set: `MATCH (n:LABEL1) WHERE ALL(x in ["LABEL2","LABEL3"] WHERE x in labels(n)) RETURN n`